# Does lvm-thin use dm-thin underneath or they are completely separate utilities?

Tags: lvm, device-mapper

LVM snapshots seem to have [extremely poor performance](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2010-November/msg00023.html)  It seems that `dm-thin` snapshots use a new implementation:

> Another significant feature is support for an arbitrary depth of
>   recursive snapshots (snapshots of snapshots of snapshots ...).  The
>   previous implementation of snapshots did this by chaining together
>   lookup tables, and so performance was O(depth).  This new
>   implementation uses a single data structure to avoid this degradation
>   with depth.  Fragmentation may still be an issue, however, in some
>   scenarios.

However, `dm-thin` seems to be pretty bare bones. In [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/thin-provisioning.txt) they say that end-users are advised to use lvm2. lvm seems to have [`lvm-thin`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmthin.7.html), so I'm wondering whether `lvm-thin` leverages `dm-thin` or whether they are different implementations and they meant that the future version of `lvm` (that don't exist yet) might leverage `dm-thin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. LVM2 is the current version of LVM, not a future version.

   ```
   $ rpm -q lvm
   package lvm is not installed
   $ rpm -q lvm2
   lvm2-2.02.177-5.fc28.x86_64
             ^ lvm 2.02 has been around for some time :)
   ```
2. LVM is very closely tied to DM; "in fact, DM is maintained by the LVM core team".  There's no independent implement of thin provisioning in the LVM layer; it depends on DM.  AFAIK there's only one "thin provisioning" implementation in DM, so its nice and simple.

I think you're right this isn't explained in any prominent documentation for lvmthin.  You could look at the LVM source code, or this [blog article](https://storageapis.wordpress.com/2016/06/24/lvm-thin-provisioning/) by a user.

Also if you use lvmthin, you will notice the devices you're using are still `/dev/mapper/...` or something related, which is straightforward to verify as being a DM device.